# PHP - @param in comment

Tags: php, oop, class, comments, param

In php, why do people sometimes have things like

```
param mixed $value
```

as comment in their code (usually found in Object-Oriented PHP)? When should you write that yourself and how exactly should you use it?
Thanks!

Comment: http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.pkg.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's used by IDEs to auto-generate tooltips and documentation, usually based on [Javadoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc).

Comment: Haha, the exactly same second :-) +1 (though my answer id is lesser :-P)

Answer (score 1):

It is written to be used with documentation generation tools and with IDEs autocompletion.

Answer (score 1):

`mixed` means it can accept several data types of the param.

Answer (score 0):

It's a standardized way of formatting comments.  You can read more about it here: http://www.phpdoc.org/about